# Growing an Iframe depending on the source inside it (which is another Server)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, size, scrollbar

I use javascript to expand an Iframe to the size of the document it loads to remove any vertical scrollbar, like so:

```
function resizeIframes() {
    $('iframe').load(function()
        {
            this.style.height = (this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 40) + 'px';
        }
    );
}
```

Which works well enough for my uses. But now I need to load the Iframe with a website from another server (actually another subdomain, instead of "www.mydomain.com" it's "services.mydomain.com") and according to Firebug I'm not allowed to read properties from other domains via Javascript. I'm guessing some kind of sandbox problem?!

Is there any way to circumvent this or at least get some kind of info about the size of the content? I even would be willing to check if there is a scrollbar and continually grow the iframe until it's gone, but unlike the window object an iframe object does not seem to have a .scrollbars property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just another subdomain, [**`document.domain`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) should give you the needed access between frames.

Comment: Yes, if you do `document.domain = "mydomain.com";` from within the iFrame document *and* from within the main document, this should work. AFAIK, you can only set document.domain from within each document (you cannot set another frame's/window's domain property), and the only allowable change is to strip subdomains from it (i.e. you can change www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com, but not the other way around, nor can you change the domain completely)

Comment: note that document.domain does not work for all versions of IE

Answer (score 1):

*I am sorry if you find this reply to be incomplete (it is). I just don't have code samples with me. I'll sketch the main concept and you will have to fill out the details yourself.*

You have to use some tricks to do that since XSS security does not allow frames from one site to access frames from another site:

- **site1:page1**: call `iframe` (`site2:page1`) on site two. Let's assume the `iframe` ID property is `"myframe"`.
- **site2:page1**: run JavaScript (in `body.onload`) to calculate the size of the current view (I think you should use `document.scrollTop` etc.). Also run an `iframe` (`site1:page2`) passing the needed width in the query string.
- **site1:page2**: read the query string and find out the requested height, update `parent.parent.document.getElementById("myframe").style.height`

Comment: If that works (I'm not sure because one of `parent` is in forbidden territory. Have you tested it?): *Clever* thinking. Hats off. Need to keep this in mind. However, this specific one can be solved easier because it's a subdomain.

Comment: the parent.parent trick is working for me in production in all major browsers (not tested in IE8 but should work). be careful about using document.domain as it is not working in some versions of IE (i think IE6 Win XP SP1) - even for subdomains